# Effect of phosphoric acid on chrome plating

Tags: reactivity, electroplating

Wondering whether phosphoric acid a suitable agent to clean chrome plated bathroom figments - a metal base shower head

Comment: Vinegar could be enough, as it is mostly lime scale.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the solubility of the resulting salt, if you use phosphoric acid on calcium lime, you get a variation on [calcium phosphate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_phosphate) (orthophosphates, di- and monohydrogen phosphates, di- and polyphosphates. Check out the solubility in water (though the solubility in $\ce{H3PO4}$ might be higher).

Consider Poutnik's suggestion to use vinegar, and the solubility of [$\ce{Ca(CH3COO)2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_acetate).

Phosphoric acid is great as a rust remover (or converter, if the phosphate film adheres), or removing other metal corrosion, though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies.
I have used vinegar in the past.
Having a proprietary phosphoric acid based rust remover I wondered whether this would be suitable for cleaning but obviously not wishing to damage the - what I assume to be - chrome on brass. And on a weaker phosphoric acid solution - I did buy some cheap carbonated sugar drink with the intention of possibly using this as a cleaning bath.
I have no usable chemistry knowledge or means of conducting tests.
Since the phosphoric acid may come with risk I may stick with vinegar.